# Make Facebook scraper not redirect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When using the Facebook dev tool to create a like button for my website, the button likes the final URL (visitors to my [site](http://www.onceuponasidewalk.com) are automatically redirected to the most recent post. I don't want to change the redirect.

What do I have to do to get the Facebook scraper to ignore the redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like button is liking wrong url](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12033162/facebook-like-button-is-liking-wrong-url)

Answer (score 0):

You don't, you need to serve content to the scraper with the meta tags for Facebook, and not serve a redirect to the scraper.

Comment: I used http://www.onceuponasidewalk.com for the url in my meta tags. Either I have no idea what I am doing and have put the meta tags in the wrong place or the scraper is still following the redirect and liking the most recent post's url.

Comment: If you put the og:url tag on a page, the crawler will go there, because the og:url tag is supposed to point to the canonical URL for a piece of content - if you want likes to accumulate on a URL which users aren't supposed to access, return meta tags to the crawler (including an og:url tag pointing to that URL), and redirect other browsers wherever you like